# Informix: create table <table name> as select * from <old table> locked the DB, how to unlock it?

Tags: informix

I was doing some R&D on table field alterations. So, I needed a clone of an table.

I ran the command "`create table <table name> as select * from <old table>`" and it worked.

However, when I ran the second time, I cancelled the command in between and after that I am getting the below error.

```
$ select count(*) from my_table_copy;
SQL -211: Cannot read system catalog (systables).
ISAM -154: ISAM error: Lock Timeout Expired
SQLSTATE: IX000 at /dev/stdin:1
```

When I tried to fetch the DB through Open Admin, there also am getting the error:

> 256 : Database query failed: -
>
> Error: -244 [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]Could not do a
>   physical-order read to fetch next row. sqlerrm(systables)
>   (SQLExecute[-244] at

How to resolve this?

Thanks,

Comment: You said "I cancelled the command in between" - how exactly did you cancel this operation? My guess is that the user session might still be hanging around holding the lock on systables.

Comment: I was doing this in command prompt in Unix. I did a Ctr-C to cancel the command. I have checked the background process and nothing is running from the OS side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be getting these lock errors, because engine is rolling back your clone table transaction.

Check with "onstat -x" if there is a transaction with an R on the flags column. The est. rb_time column shows an estimate of recovery complete process.

My suggestion? If you don't need exactly the same actual data on the new table, you can put a "SET ISOLATION TO DIRTY READ;" right before your create table command.

Comment: Thank you Alexandre. The issue got resolved after an hour. The table was huge and as you said, the roll back has taken that much time. I like your suggestion to set dirty read, since actual data can wary and for R&D we only need a big set, not exact set. Thank you.